# Why JpaRepository<User, Long> returns null value

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a Spring Boot project, in which I have problem with `JpaRepository<User,Long>`.

I defined following interface

```
public interface UserDAO extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    User findByEmail(String email);
}
```

which was implemented in `UserServiceImpl`

```
@Override
public User findByEmail(String email) {
    return userDAO.findByEmail(email);
}
```

and I need it in `UserDetailsServiceImpl` but next line

```
User user = userDAO.findByEmail(email);
```

returns null.

My model classes:

User

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "login")
    private String login;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "user_roles",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Set<Role> roles;

    @Transient
    private String confirmPassword;
    //getters-setters

}
```

Role

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
public class Role implements GrantedAuthority {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
    private Set<User> users;
```

What can I do?

Comment: Try `@Repository` annotation in UserDAO interface and `@Service` in your service class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to follow JavaBean specification for entity(you need to have default contrucor and getters and setters in User and Role)

Comment: And also why you create another method here:

    public interface UserDAO extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
        User findByEmail(String email);
    }

I think that mathod findByEmail already exists in JpaRepository, you dont need to specify again

Comment: i have deafult fields, im following OOP principles, so methods which JpaRepository hasn't will be implemented in UserServiceImpl

Comment: But with spring i think you need to follow java bean specification, but then in service you call your findByEmail not from Jpa which is automatilly generated

Comment: nah, i call method from jpa `return userDAO.findByEmail(email);`

Comment: But that is your method from Jpa it is not method from Jpa which is automaticly generated with reflection from your entity User

Comment: Try to remove your method User findByEmail(String email); from UserDAO

Comment: And also create getters and setters in User

Comment: but my UserDAO extends JpaRepository

Comment: it has getters and setters

Comment: if it extends JpaRepository why are you adding fingByEmail, JpaRepository needs to have it by default

Comment: try this:     public interface UserDAO extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {} and check if you already have findByEmail

Comment: methods which JpaRepository hasn't will be implemented in UserServiceImpl

Comment: yep. i have....

Comment: Did you write some sql or something in UserServiceImpl?

Comment: And in UserServiceImpl you initalize UserDao with @Autowired anotation

Comment: nope............

Comment: Great tutorial about spring boot so you can check --> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9SGDpanrc8U

Comment: Let me know if you resolve that problem

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the annotations on the getter, not the fields.

Comment: nothing. I'm also getting null

Comment: Can you tell the emailbox-address?

Comment: kononchuk99999@gmail.com

Comment: Hm, is a plain old emailboxaddress. I dont know.